# How to get WIFI signal Strength in dBm in iOS Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi

How to get WIFI signal Strength in **dBm** in iOS Programmatically.

I have implemented the MobileWiFi.framework code in sample app also.

But I am getting the following error Because MobileWiFi.framework missed in Project, and I could not get from any sample apps.

**WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices**, referenced from:

**[ViewController getWifiSignalStregth:]** in ViewController

Here is the sample code that I have used.

```
-(IBAction)getWifiSignalStregth:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"getWifiSignalStregth Called");


    WiFiManagerRef manager = WiFiManagerClientCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFArrayRef devices = WiFiManagerClientCopyDevices(manager);

    WiFiDeviceClientRef client = (WiFiDeviceClientRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(devices, 0);
    CFDictionaryRef data = (CFDictionaryRef)WiFiDeviceClientCopyProperty(client, CFSTR("RSSI"));
    CFNumberRef scaled = (CFNumberRef)WiFiDeviceClientCopyProperty(client, kWiFiScaledRSSIKey);

    CFNumberRef RSSI = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(data, CFSTR("RSSI_CTL_AGR"));

    int raw;
    CFNumberGetValue(RSSI, kCFNumberIntType, &raw);

    float strength;
    CFNumberGetValue(scaled, kCFNumberFloatType, &strength);
    CFRelease(scaled);

    strength *= -1;

    // Apple uses -3.0.
    int bars = (int)ceilf(strength * -3.0f);
    bars = MAX(1, MIN(bars, 3));


    printf("WiFi signal strength: %d dBm\n\t Bars: %d\n", raw,  bars);

    CFRelease(data);
    CFRelease(scaled);
    CFRelease(devices);
    CFRelease(manager);



}
```

Comment: Try to add these frameworks : 1. https://github.com/Cykey/wifi                             2. https://github.com/Cykey/airscan

Comment: I downloaded "Stumbler" Earlier and now as well, But it is saying You can’t open the application “Stumbler” because it is not supported on this type of Mac. and it is developed in 2007, Might be it will not work now.

Comment: I run the makefile under "Cykey/wifi" , But I am getting the following error.


/Users/Downloads/airscan-master/Makefile: line 1: export: `=': not a valid identifier
/Users/Downloads/airscan-master/Makefile: line 3: THEOS_PROJECT_DIR: command not found
 etc

Comment: @RXGangam Did you solve it? Do we need to import any frameworks for `WiFiManagerRef `? Could you provide the sample code, please?